# Consolidate contents of embedded file into original document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a VBA script that finds all embedded (.docx) files within a Word Document, and copies their contents into the parent document, replacing the embedded object with text.
I am able to find the embedded objects using:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToObject, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:= _
    "Word.Document.12"
```

However it is unclear to me how to open this selected object, and -- more importantly -- interact with the opened file through the same script. Before I get too far ahead of myself, is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (lightly tested...)

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim cDocs As Collection
    Dim o As InlineShape

    Set cDocs = GetEmbeddedDocs(ActiveDocument)
    For Each o In cDocs
        o.OLEFormat.Open
        With ActiveDocument
            .Content.Copy
            .Close
        End With
        o.Select
        Selection.Paste
    Next o
End Sub


Function GetEmbeddedDocs(oDoc As Word.Document) As Collection
    Dim o As InlineShape
    Dim c As New Collection

    For Each o In oDoc.InlineShapes
        If o.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
            If o.OLEFormat.ProgID Like "Word.Document.*" Then
                c.Add o
            End If
        End If
    Next o
    Set GetEmbeddedDocs = c
End Function
```

Comment: Wow. This worked perfectly! I also just learned a half dozen new VBA techniques in the process, so thanks for that as well!